# iPad/iPod not recognized in iTunes/Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, itunes, ios

I have an iPad 3 and a 4th Gen iPod, neither of which will show up in iTunes on Windows 10 Anniversary Update. I've tried two different sync cables and 3 different USB ports, and I've re-installed iTunes. Apple Mobile Device Service, Bonjour Service, iPod Service all running, but iTunes does not open automatically when I connect a device.

Both of these devices spend most of their time in very specific roles (iPad sits in a kiosk as a print-release station for a copier, the iPod connects to our PBX via the headphone jack for music on hold — long story there) and only rarely come back to my desk to sync. Both synced without issue about 4 1/2 months ago. I am able to use Windows Explorer to browse the pictures stored on both devices as if they were digital cameras (the iPad prompts me to Allow this first) and they both show up in the "Portable Devices" category in Device Manager with reasonable names.

Any ideas?

Comment: fwiw, I opted to ask here rather than the Apple stack exchange because the failure by two different devices makes me believe the problem is with Windows somewhere.

Comment: You have installed and updated iTunes I assume?  I had no problem with my own iPad and Windows 10, tested it against all my Windows 10 VMs, and they all connected.

Comment: > `"and I've re-installed iTunes"`

Comment: Which version of windows 10? I am running the version with less bloatware (10N) and it fails to work with all kinds of things like smartphones.

Comment: Anniversary Update... and that might be the biggest change since July when things worked.

Comment: Is the apple bonjour service running?

Comment: Apple Mobile Device Service, Bonjour Service, iPod Service all running.

Comment: All info here is not included in the question.

Answer (score 1):

After some more digging, it seems Windows detects this as an "`MTP USB Device`" in the Portable Devices section in Device Manager. At least, that's the driver it uses. My searching indicates it should be using an "`Apple Mobile Device Driver`" under the Universal Serial Bus Controller.

To get Windows to use the other driver, I choose "`Update Driver Software`" in the Device Manager, then "`Browse my Local Computer for Driver Software`" and "`Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my compute`r". Now I click the "`Have Disk...`" button, which lets me browse to "`C:\Program Files\Common Files\Apple\Mobile Device Support\Drivers`", which has a driver *.inf I can choose, and which did eventually allow me to connect my iPad.

I had to do this separately for both devices, but the second time through the browse option was already pointed to the right place, so it went much more quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Mine wouldn't work until I tried a USB 3.0 port and cable.  The 2.0 ports failed to register it at all.